# ImprtErr: cannot import name 'ExtraValues' from 'pydantic.config' (C:\Users\bbchs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\config.cp311-win_amd64.pyd)

Tags: openai-api, code-interpreter

```
from codeinterpreterapi import CodeInterpreterSession, settings
```

## create a session and close it automatically

with CodeInterpreterSession() as session:

```
response = session.generate_response(
    "Plot the bitcoin chart of year 2023"
)
# output the response
response.show()
```

Comment: How can I fix the import error : ImportError: cannot import name 'ExtraValues' from 'pydantic.config' (C:\Users\bbchs\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\config.cp311-win_amd64.pyd)

Comment: I installed - pip install "codeinterpreterapi[all]" as per the documentation